# Ошибка:Segmentation fault (core dumped): как можно исправить (Shared Memory) C++

Tags: c++, linux, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
int main()
{
    int ShmID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1024, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(ShmID == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot create shared memory" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t ChildPid = fork();
    if(ChildPid == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot fork" << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }
    std::queue<std::string>* str = (std::queue<std::string>*)shmat(ShmID, 0, 0);
    if(str == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot attach shared memory" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }
    if(ChildPid == 0)
    {
        //CHild process
        str->push("hello");
        str->push("world");
        shmdt(str);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //parent process
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << str->front() << ' ';
        str->pop();
        std::cout << str->front() << ' ';
        str->pop();

        shmdt(str);
        shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка слишком проста - Вы пытаетесь обращаться к объекту, который не создали

```
std::queue<std::string>* str = (std::queue<std::string>*)shmat(ShmID, 0, 0);
```

то есть, str указывает на память, но что там... а кто его знает. Если обычную структуру так можно размещать, то с++ классы нужно только через конструктор.

```
// получим указатель на память
void *p = shmat(ShmID, 0, 0);
// используем placement new для создания объекта по месту
std::queue<std::string> * str = new(p)std::queue<std::string>();
```

после такого изменения уже не падает. Но нужно не забыть вызвать деструктор (`delete str;`). И видимо его нужно вызвать только в одном из процессов. И самое главное - не вызвать его тогда, когда ещё другой процесс использует его.

Также нужно аккуратно посинхронизировать обращения к памяти, а то может быть очень  весело - std::queue не ожидает, что он работает с разных процессов.

Comment: я изменил, так как вы сказали но не помогло:

Comment: У себя я тестил, оно заработало (хотя все написанное - хак и с++ классы лучше не переносить через границу процессов)

Comment: А может проблема где то в другом месте потому что не как не работает у меня. Или можем как то хорошем разделить память между процессом что процесси поняли как очередь ?

Comment: Если там кода ещё сотни строк, то вполне может и не работать. А в целом, в  линуксе уже есть queue для этого "из коробки" (то есть , из ядра) https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-mq_notify/

Comment: нет код столько сколько я отправил но не работает но спасибо

Comment: ок, не работает - падает, выводит не то, что ожидается, взрывается комп

Comment: на вопрос смотрите я там писал на чтом проблема. в терминале пишет Segmentation fault (core dumped).