# Межпроцессное взаимодействие в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory

Как можно разделить память между процессами, чтобы процессы эту память поняли, как очередь(queue) на C++ в Linux?
Спасибо.

Comment: Миллион способов, начиная от выписывания собственных классов, до использования готовых.

Comment: можете отправить уже готовый код я не как не могу найти спасибо.

Comment: Полудуплексные каналы UNIX, именные каналы, очереди сообщений, разделенная память... В общем очень много [способов](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html).

Comment: Ternvein  я попробовал на разделенная память но выдает ошыбка на segmentation fault и я некак не могу найти в чем проблема.

Comment: я подозреваю что проблема здесь...
void *p = shmat(ShmID, 0, 0);
std::queue<std::string> * str = new(p)std::queue<std::string>();

Comment: проблема не в разделяемой памяти, а в том, что с++ классы плохо просто так в ней живут.

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769259/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0segmentation-fault-core-dumped-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-shared-memory-c/769285?noredirect=1#comment1199181_769285

Comment: этот вопрос я задавал но не помогли

Comment: Для этого нужно переписывать аллокаторы так, чтобы сами элементы создавались в этой разделяемой памяти. Иначе ерунда получается - вы в одном процессе кладете элементы в очередь, они создаются в памяти процесса (не разделяемой), а потом пробуете обратиться из другого. и то не уверен, что все получится - слабо представляю Linux - будут ли там одни и те же адреса в разных процессах для общей памяти?

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать стандартные очереди сообщений? И ничего изобретать не нужно. Посмотрите главы 5 и 6 в книге "UNIX: взаимодействие процессов" Уильям Стивенс. Там всё очень просто рассказывается.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584678/how-do-i-synchronize-access-to-shared-memory-in-lynxos-posix).